# SafeQ Linux Client

Tags: cups

I installed SafeQ Client for Linux by installing libcrafter and ysoft-client debs. 
However, my printer (Konica Minolta bizhub 224e) won't print it
and all jobs are canceled by CUPS.

I never got username and password window up to send them, which is needed by SafeQ server to authenticate me.

This worked before on Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. Now I am using Mint 17.2 KDE (KDE 4.13). Can someone get me on the right track what could be the issue here?

---

References:

- [YSoft SafeQ<sup>®</sup> Client for Linux / Installation and usage Guide](http://www.satikos.cz/download/safeq-client-for-linux/YSQ-Client-for-Linux-Installation-and-Usage-Guide-en.pdf) –
  a 14-page PDF.
- [Linux client for YSoft SafeQ](https://is.muni.cz/th/409878/fi_b/BachelorThesis-DavidKaya.pdf) (a 63-page PDF!) –
  the bachelor thesis of Dávid Kaya, containing the design, requirements analysis
  and test report for the (Linux) YSoft SafeQ Client.
- [Information about the libcrafter and ysoft-client debs](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B67ZDYW07PDufkdMenl6M0E1THlzYUZKaGNzc18yb1hicEhYMlhmSkxIN2psaVFHeXZBTEE&usp=sharing&tid=0B67ZDYW07PDufmV0SzZnVFZaR09yeVNOOF9QX0VzY28tRFZNRDJ5X2ZIV1NqYWlTT3F6bXM) –
  a protected Google document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a issue with default-qt5 package in KDE Plasma 4.x. When installing in Kubuntu with KDE Plasma 5.4 the client ysoft-client-kde runs and everything is fine. Also in Cinnamon 2.6.13 with Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit ysoft-client-gnome is running. So, this doesn't work only in KDE Plasma 4.x due to some qt4 - qt5 issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to install it with [these instructions](https://it.muni.cz/en/services/print-services-for-students/instructions/print-from-your-pc-linux) (here slightly changed) on Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS:

- unpack archive from https://it.muni.cz/media/3447407/ysoft_safeq_client_for_linux.7z
- Change into "ysoft_safeq_client_for_linux"
- run following to install `libgnome-keyring0`: `sudo apt install -f ./*.deb`
- change into "Debian package"
- run to install `libcrafter` and `ysoft-client`: `sudo apt install -f ./*.deb`